# Separator in Dart Numbers. For example 1_234_567

Tags: flutter, dart

In Javascript and Java, you could write one billion and one like this: `1_000_000_001` and that's the same as `1000000001`.

As you can see, the former is clearly way more readable.

What's the equivalent of this in Dart? If nothing is available, is this in the roadmap ?

Comment: It's not implemented. see here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2

Comment: It's simply `1e9 + 1`